# How to call Scala method with Class[_] parameter from Java?

Tags: scala

So I'm trying to write a Proxy client to a JSON-RPC service, in Scala. It creates a proxy Service object using a Factory that I can directly calls method and Proxy object's custom invocation handler will send the request thru the wire. The Factory is like this:

```
ProxyFactory.newAPIProxy(service: Class[_]): AnyRef
```

Then if I have a Trait like

```
trait EchoService {
    def echo(str: String): String
}
```

I can get the service object with

```
ProxyFactory.newAPIProxy(classOf[EchoService])
```

Now the problem is, I want to use this client in Java classes with Java interfaces and I can't get it to compile. My interface is like:

```
interface EchoService {
    String echo(String str)
}
```

and when I call

```
EchoService s = (EchoService) ProxyFactory.newAPIProxy(EchoService.class)
```

it doesn't compile... I thought .class in Java is equivalent to Class[_] in Scala. I'm new to Scala and have no idea what to search for solutions to this problem!! Please help >.<

Comment: The Java equivalent of `Class[_]` is `Class<?>`, and `EchoService.class` returns `Class<EchoService>`. So this seems like it should work.

Comment: Sorry this actually works and I was reading the wrong compile error and highlights from the IDE. Please feel free to remove this question. Thanks for all your help!